# Why am I getting a NoRegionError when using aws_athena_hook in airflow?

Tags: etl, boto3, airflow, amazon-athena

I am trying to use *airflow* to *run a query in Athena using airflow on a schedule.*

The function that I have enclosed below is run using **`PythonOperator`** in `airflow`.

```
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.contrib.hooks.aws_athena_hook import AWSAthenaHook
import datetime

def update_athena_partition(*args, **kwargs):
    execution_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(kwargs['ds'], '%Y-%m-%d')
    execution_month = execution_date.month
    execution_year = execution_date.year
    s3_prefix = Variable.get('bikeshare_s3_prefix')
    bucket_name = Variable.get('bikeshare_bucket_name')
    athena_table_name = Variable.get('bikeshare_athena_table')
    result_configuration = {"OutputLocation": "s3://{}/".format(bucket_name)}
    file_location = 's3://bucket_name/' + s3_prefix + f'year=2018/month=2/'
    partition_update_query = """
    ALTER TABLE {} add partition (year="{}", month='{}')
    location "{}";
    """
    athena_hook = AWSAthenaHook(aws_conn_id='aws_credentials')
    athena_hook.run_query(partition_update_query.format(athena_table_name,
                                                        2018,
                                                        2,
                                                        file_location),
                          result_configuration=result_configuration,
                          query_context="athena_database_name")
```

This is my DAG

```
etl_dag = DAG(
    'ETL_pipeline',
    start_date=datetime.datetime.now()
```

I have tried the query in Athena's GUI and the query works perfectly.

When I trigger the DAG to run, **this is the error I get**

```
*** Reading local file: /Users/vj/Documents/My_Mac/Projects/etl_athena_redshift_airflow/airflow/logs/Bikeshare_ETL/Update_partition_schema.task/2019-08-13T02:06:13.072895+00:00/1.log
[2019-08-12 22:09:18,845] {taskinstance.py:616} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: Bikeshare_ETL.Update_partition_schema.task 2019-08-13T02:06:13.072895+00:00 [queued]>
[2019-08-12 22:09:18,856] {taskinstance.py:616} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: Bikeshare_ETL.Update_partition_schema.task 2019-08-13T02:06:13.072895+00:00 [queued]>
[2019-08-12 22:09:18,856] {taskinstance.py:834} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2019-08-12 22:09:18,856] {taskinstance.py:835} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2019-08-12 22:09:18,856] {taskinstance.py:836} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2019-08-12 22:09:18,863] {taskinstance.py:855} INFO - Executing <Task(PythonOperator): Update_partition_schema.task> on 2019-08-13T02:06:13.072895+00:00
[2019-08-12 22:09:18,864] {base_task_runner.py:133} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'run', 'Bikeshare_ETL', 'Update_partition_schema.task', '2019-08-13T02:06:13.072895+00:00', '--job_id', '24', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--raw', '-sd', 'DAGS_FOLDER/bikeshare_etl.py', '--cfg_path', '/var/folders/lq/9rht3n895x77gfzqtpwq2nbh0000gn/T/tmphp_qjc4o']
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,438] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task [2019-08-12 22:09:19,438] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,739] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task [2019-08-12 22:09:19,738] {dagbag.py:90} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /Users/vj/Documents/My_Mac/Projects/etl_athena_redshift_airflow/airflow/dags/bikeshare_etl.py
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,813] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task [2019-08-12 22:09:19,813] {cli.py:516} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: Bikeshare_ETL.Update_partition_schema.task 2019-08-13T02:06:13.072895+00:00 [running]> on host Vijays-MacBook-Pro.local
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,820] {python_operator.py:105} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=Bikeshare_ETL
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=Update_partition_schema.task
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2019-08-13T02:06:13.072895+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=manual__2019-08-13T02:06:13.072895+00:00
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,871] {taskinstance.py:1047} ERROR - You must specify a region.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vj/Documents/My_Mac/Projects/etl_athena_redshift_airflow/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 922, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/Users/vj/Documents/My_Mac/Projects/etl_athena_redshift_airflow/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 113, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/Users/vj/Documents/My_Mac/Projects/etl_athena_redshift_airflow/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 118, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/Users/vj/Documents/My_Mac/Projects/etl_athena_redshift_airflow/airflow/dags/bikeshare_etl.py", line 107, in update_athena_partition
    query_context="bikeshare_data")
  File "/Users/vj/Documents/My_Mac/Projects/etl_athena_redshift_airflow/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/aws_athena_hook.py", line 67, in run_query
    response = self.get_conn().start_query_execution(QueryString=query,
  File "/Users/vj/Documents/My_Mac/Projects/etl_athena_redshift_airflow/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/aws_athena_hook.py", line 50, in get_conn
    self.conn = self.get_client_type('athena')
  File "/Users/vj/Documents/My_Mac/Projects/etl_athena_redshift_airflow/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/aws_hook.py", line 170, in get_client_type
    config=config, verify=self.verify)
  File "/Users/vj/Documents/My_Mac/Projects/etl_athena_redshift_airflow/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/session.py", line 263, in client
    aws_session_token=aws_session_token, config=config)
  File "/Users/vj/Documents/My_Mac/Projects/etl_athena_redshift_airflow/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 839, in create_client
    client_config=config, api_version=api_version)
  File "/Users/vj/Documents/My_Mac/Projects/etl_athena_redshift_airflow/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 86, in create_client
    verify, credentials, scoped_config, client_config, endpoint_bridge)
  File "/Users/vj/Documents/My_Mac/Projects/etl_athena_redshift_airflow/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 328, in _get_client_args
    verify, credentials, scoped_config, client_config, endpoint_bridge)
  File "/Users/vj/Documents/My_Mac/Projects/etl_athena_redshift_airflow/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/args.py", line 47, in get_client_args
    endpoint_url, is_secure, scoped_config)
  File "/Users/vj/Documents/My_Mac/Projects/etl_athena_redshift_airflow/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/args.py", line 117, in compute_client_args
    service_name, region_name, endpoint_url, is_secure)
  File "/Users/vj/Documents/My_Mac/Projects/etl_athena_redshift_airflow/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 402, in resolve
    service_name, region_name)
  File "/Users/vj/Documents/My_Mac/Projects/etl_athena_redshift_airflow/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/regions.py", line 122, in construct_endpoint
    partition, service_name, region_name)
  File "/Users/vj/Documents/My_Mac/Projects/etl_athena_redshift_airflow/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/regions.py", line 135, in _endpoint_for_partition
    raise NoRegionError()
botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region.
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,875] {taskinstance.py:1078} INFO - Marking task as FAILED.
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,888] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task Traceback (most recent call last):
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,888] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task   File "/Users/vj/Documents/My_Mac/Projects/etl_athena_redshift_airflow/.venv/bin/airflow", line 32, in <module>
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,888] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task     args.func(args)
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,888] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task   File "/Users/vj/Documents/My_Mac/Projects/etl_athena_redshift_airflow/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 74, in wrapper
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,888] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task     return f(*args, **kwargs)
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,888] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task   File "/Users/vj/Documents/My_Mac/Projects/etl_athena_redshift_airflow/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 522, in run
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,888] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task     _run(args, dag, ti)
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,888] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task   File "/Users/vj/Documents/My_Mac/Projects/etl_athena_redshift_airflow/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 440, in _run
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,888] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task     pool=args.pool,
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,888] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task   File "/Users/vj/Documents/My_Mac/Projects/etl_athena_redshift_airflow/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 74, in wrapper
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,888] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task     return func(*args, **kwargs)
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,888] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task   File "/Users/vj/Documents/My_Mac/Projects/etl_athena_redshift_airflow/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 922, in _run_raw_task
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,888] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task     result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,889] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task   File "/Users/vj/Documents/My_Mac/Projects/etl_athena_redshift_airflow/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 113, in execute
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,889] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task     return_value = self.execute_callable()
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,889] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task   File "/Users/vj/Documents/My_Mac/Projects/etl_athena_redshift_airflow/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 118, in execute_callable
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,889] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task     return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,889] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task   File "/Users/vj/Documents/My_Mac/Projects/etl_athena_redshift_airflow/airflow/dags/bikeshare_etl.py", line 107, in update_athena_partition
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,889] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task     query_context="bikeshare_data")
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,889] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task   File "/Users/vj/Documents/My_Mac/Projects/etl_athena_redshift_airflow/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/aws_athena_hook.py", line 67, in run_query
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,889] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task     response = self.get_conn().start_query_execution(QueryString=query,
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,889] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task   File "/Users/vj/Documents/My_Mac/Projects/etl_athena_redshift_airflow/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/aws_athena_hook.py", line 50, in get_conn
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,889] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task     self.conn = self.get_client_type('athena')
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,889] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task   File "/Users/vj/Documents/My_Mac/Projects/etl_athena_redshift_airflow/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/aws_hook.py", line 170, in get_client_type
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,889] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task     config=config, verify=self.verify)
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,889] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task   File "/Users/vj/Documents/My_Mac/Projects/etl_athena_redshift_airflow/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/session.py", line 263, in client
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,889] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task     aws_session_token=aws_session_token, config=config)
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,889] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task   File "/Users/vj/Documents/My_Mac/Projects/etl_athena_redshift_airflow/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 839, in create_client
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,889] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task     client_config=config, api_version=api_version)
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,889] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task   File "/Users/vj/Documents/My_Mac/Projects/etl_athena_redshift_airflow/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 86, in create_client
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,889] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task     verify, credentials, scoped_config, client_config, endpoint_bridge)
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,889] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task   File "/Users/vj/Documents/My_Mac/Projects/etl_athena_redshift_airflow/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 328, in _get_client_args
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,889] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task     verify, credentials, scoped_config, client_config, endpoint_bridge)
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,889] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task   File "/Users/vj/Documents/My_Mac/Projects/etl_athena_redshift_airflow/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/args.py", line 47, in get_client_args
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,889] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task     endpoint_url, is_secure, scoped_config)
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,889] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task   File "/Users/vj/Documents/My_Mac/Projects/etl_athena_redshift_airflow/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/args.py", line 117, in compute_client_args
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,889] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task     service_name, region_name, endpoint_url, is_secure)
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,890] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task   File "/Users/vj/Documents/My_Mac/Projects/etl_athena_redshift_airflow/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 402, in resolve
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,890] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task     service_name, region_name)
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,890] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task   File "/Users/vj/Documents/My_Mac/Projects/etl_athena_redshift_airflow/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/regions.py", line 122, in construct_endpoint
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,890] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task     partition, service_name, region_name)
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,890] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task   File "/Users/vj/Documents/My_Mac/Projects/etl_athena_redshift_airflow/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/regions.py", line 135, in _endpoint_for_partition
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,890] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task     raise NoRegionError()
[2019-08-12 22:09:19,890] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 24: Subtask Update_partition_schema.task botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region.
[2019-08-12 22:09:23,848] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [[34m2019-08-12 22:09:23,847[0m] {[34mlocal_task_job.py:[0m105} INFO[0m - Task exited with return code 1[0m
```

Kindly help me figure out what I am missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From log you would need to specify the region. `botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region.`

I think it might be related to how you set up the connection there, `athena_hook = AWSAthenaHook(aws_conn_id='aws_credentials')`, check your connection id `aws_credentials` and you need to specify the region there.

Under "extra" you can put the region information like `{"region_name": "us-east-1"}`

Some code detail of calling [aws_hook](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/157170ba4c5bb2d45246ae70ae69140556e11562/airflow/contrib/hooks/aws_hook.py#L121-L122) in airflow

Comment: Thanks a lot. That solved the issue. However, Now im getting an error stating that `clientRequestToken` should get a string argument whereas it received None (default argument). Do you have any idea on how to solve this? @Chengzhi

Comment: I haven't use AWSAthenaHook before, but after reading the code, I think you can pass `str(uuid4())` to just avoid multiple executions of same query. https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/157170ba4c5bb2d45246ae70ae69140556e11562/airflow/contrib/hooks/aws_athena_hook.py#L66-L67
and https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/c8c7126593921322cc4f131ee318607cb893520c/airflow/contrib/operators/aws_athena_operator.py#L62